# Pyspark How to do reverse of groupby count?

Tags: function, pyspark

**Input dataframe:**

| class | malecount | femalecount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 |
| B | 3 | 1 |
| C | 0 | 3 |
| D | 2 | 4 |

**Expected Output dataframe:**

| Class | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| A | m |
| A | m |
| B | m |
| B | m |
| B | m |
| D | m |
| D | m |
| A | f |
| B | f |
| C | f |
| C | f |
| C | f |
| D | f |
| D | f |
| D | f |
| D | f |

Answer (score 1):

you can create male and female arrays for each class and then explode it.

see example below

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('male_arr', func.expr('concat_ws(",", array_repeat("m", cast(malecount as int)))')). \
    withColumn('female_arr', func.expr('concat_ws(",", array_repeat("f", cast(femalecount as int)))')). \
    withColumn('male_female', func.concat_ws(',', 
                                             func.expr('if(male_arr="", null, male_arr)'), 
                                             func.expr('if(female_arr="", null, female_arr)')
                                             )
               ). \
    selectExpr('class', 'explode(split(male_female, ",")) as gender'). \
    show()

# +-----+------+
# |class|gender|
# +-----+------+
# |    A|     m|
# |    A|     m|
# |    A|     f|
# |    B|     m|
# |    B|     m|
# |    B|     m|
# |    B|     f|
# |    C|     f|
# |    C|     f|
# |    C|     f|
# |    D|     m|
# |    D|     m|
# |    D|     f|
# |    D|     f|
# |    D|     f|
# |    D|     f|
# +-----+------+
```